# PHP selects the same rows from different process

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a PHP script to fetch rows from database and process it.

```
while(true){
     SELECT FROM table WHERE process = 0

     UPDATED the selected rows status

     etc.....
}
```

It will select the row where process = 0 one-by-one and proceed.

Then i used to run that php file in multiple tabs ( Process1, process2, process3 etc...).

But the problem is that the two process selects same row while running as multi-process.
I need the process to skip the row that was already selected by another process.

Comment: You need to use transactions or locking.

Comment: It's possible that you could achieve this in a single query, but we'd need the details of your current queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to select and lock the row, then update it.

Comment: will the process2 will skip that locked row or process the row again after process1 completed it operation

Comment: @Prem, the rows will be locked for both reading and writing, so the second process will wait until the rows are released before the `SELECT` query completes. So you could have another field, say, `is_processing`, which you could set to `1` with the `UPDATE`, then the second process's logic could skip all rows with `is_processing` set to `1`.